# How to create a Windows mail addin

Tags: c#, email, uwp

I am trying to create a Windows Mail plugin (addin) for Windows (Universal Windows Platform) UWP. I know that I must declare the Capabilities, and that email is a 'restricted capability', but still it can be used, the only drawback is that it could not be uploaded to Windows store. My question is how to intercept the send event, Eg: on send I want the user to confirm some stuffs and only then, send the mail.
Can anyone please helpme on this ?

Comment: Windows Mail does not support plugins.  You can't do that.

Comment: I have been told that by side loading i can make it

Comment: By side loading, you can make it read email.  But you can't interact with the Windows Mail UI.

Comment: So, isn't there a way that my app can react to new email event ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Email

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but even looking at the API, there not seems to be a way to find out when an email is sent, or about to do so...

Comment: Yes; you can't do that.